# Android dynamically calculate number of columns

Tags: android, layout, adapter, dynamic-columns

I have a dynamically created list of items which should be displayed in either two or one column depending on the space the containing text needs e.g. if the text is long it will only be one item per row, otherwise two. Obviously they should all be the same size (half the screen size).

As far as I know there's no standard Android view with Adapter that does that. With a GridView you can have multiple columns, but not some rows one column and others two. A TableLayout could stretch views, but also here you have to know how many columns you need per row. Plus it doesn't have an Adapter.

So what I want to know a) is there any control that I'm missing that supports something like this or b) what would be the easiest solution for this problem?

**EDIT:** the items also contain a CheckBox and I need to keep track of the checked state so I can't just put two items in one view using an Adapter.

Comment: Do you mean that each item should be generated by an adapter, and if one item is narrow enough, the next item will be on the same row? If so, what if item 0 is narrow, item 1 is wide and item 2 is narrow, should all items be on separate rows? Or do you mean that each item has two bits of data, and where only one of the bits will be visible if it is too wide?

Comment: Yes it's the first option. And the requirement is that if item 1 is wide it should be in the next row or if item 0 is wide item 1 should be in the next row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know there is no ready solution for your problem. I haven't yet tried something like this, but I would use a LinearLayout as the list item. Then just create your own Deflater (e.g. CursorAdapter) that deflates the Layout and checks the length. If needed you should be able to add a new View (e.g. TextView) to the LinearLayout.

Comment: hm yes. the problem is that it's not just a TextView. it's a CheckBox with text and I also need to keep track of the checked items. So ideally every one of the items has one view.

Comment: Another idea: Just create two columns and set one to visibility:gone if you don't need it. The TextView was just an example. If you wrap your complex layout into another layout you can add it to a LinearLayout too.

Comment: It might work for me. I'll give it a try. If that works I guess it's the easiest solution.. everything else would just be adding views in code.

Comment: yep that seems to work. i just set the row to gone if the item's already been displayed in the previous row... probably not a nice solution but the easiest

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that this is a hard problem to solve using standard components, due to the problem of mapping data to items to rows.

If you for example use a `Cursor` with `x` rows to feed the adapter with data, then the total item count as seen from the `Adapter` is also `x`. However, since you're conditionally mapping two items to the same row, it means that a `ListView` will see `y` rows in the `Adapter`, where `y <= x`. But you cannot easily tell from the beginning what `y` will be. Furthermore, if the `ListView` asks the `Adapter` for item i where 0 <= i < y, there would be no (easy) way for the `Adapter` to determine which elements from the `Cursor` that `i` would map to.

That being said, a viable solution would be to subclass `AdapterView` or `ListView` and implement the layout of the elements yourself. As you're getting each item from the `Adapter`, you'll measure and layout it, depending on the sizes of the surrounding adapter items.

A different solution that could work for you if you don't have a large number of elements is to use two custom `Adapter`s, one called `ItemAdapter` and one called `RowAdapter`. The `ItemAdapter` will inflate the actual items based on (the presumed) `Cursor`. The `RowAdapter` will use the `ItemAdapter` to get the items and merge them into rows. The `ListView` will in turn use the `RowAdapter`. The issue is that to know how many rows the `RowAdapter` will produce, it is necessary to measure all the items from `ItemAdapter` before the `RowAdapter` is connected to the `ListView`.

Comment: That sounds like a nicer solution. For now I just check for each row if the item has already been displayed or not, otherwise I set the row to invisible. That works for me, because I only have to know the states of the CheckBoxes once the user clicks an OK button on the screen.